# Zabbix: Last Line of a Textfile

Tags: zabbix

Has anyone a solution for my problem:

We have a textfile which is always updated when a new error occurs.
I want to monitor this text file in Zabbix. I have been looking for a solution for some time and have now managed this with vfs.file.contents[ErrorLog.log,ANSI].  But here always the whole logfile is read.

Is there a way to read only the last line of a text file in Zabbix?
Since the text file changes with each error I need only the last line.

Thanks and greetings
Kai

Comment: Why not write a custom command for it?

Answer (score 0):

You need `log[]`, see
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/itemtypes/log_items

If the file is rotated/overwritten, you need `logrt[]`, same documentation page.

Comment: im gonna try this out.